# kotlin sqlite How can I update only a certain line of the id I want?

Tags: android, sql, kotlin

editTextText'te id'ye gireceğim. EditTextNumber'da yaşa gireceğim. Button2'a tıkladığımda sadece yaşın güncellenmesini istiyorum. Çok denedim ama yapamadım. Öğrenmeye çalışıyorum. Kotlin hakkında fazla bilgi bulamıyorum.Bana yardım edersen memnun olurum.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextNumber"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="kaydet"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editTextNumber"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editTextNumber"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextNumber" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="güncelle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextText2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="136dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

kullanici.kt

```
    class kullanici {
    var id:Int=0
    var adsoyad:String=""
    var yasi:Int=0
    constructor(adsoyad:String,yasi:Int){
        this.adsoyad =adsoyad
        this.yasi =yasi
    }
    constructor(){}
}
```

DataBaseHelper.kt

```
val database_name = "veritabanim"
val table_name = "kullanicilar"
val col_name = "adisoyadi"
val col_age = "yasi"
val col_id = "id"
class DataBaseHelper (var context: Context):SQLiteOpenHelper(context,
    database_name,null,1) {
    override fun onCreate(p0: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        var createTable = " CREATE TABLE "+ table_name+"("+
                col_id +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                col_name +" VARCHAR(256),"+
                col_age +" INTEGER)"
        p0?.execSQL(createTable)
    }
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
    val context = this
    var db = DataBaseHelper(context) 
binding.button2.setOnClickListener(){ ? }
```